# HTML href Link is not clickable

Tags: html, google-apps-script, evernote

I want to send the following snippet to my gmail account, **however it does not resolve into a clickable link in the email I recieve.**

```
<a href="evernote:///view/XXXXXXX/sXX/f473d94d-ac3d-43d0-a838-0c9f55d622c6/f473d94d-ac3d-43d0-a838-0c9f55d622c6/">Link</a>
```

Full Code (JavaScript / Google Apps Script)

```
function test() {
GmailApp.sendEmail("X.X@gmail.com", "Mail Subject", "",{ htmlBody: "<a href='evernote:///view/XXXXXXX/sXX/f473d94d-ac3d-43d0-a838-0c9f55d622c6/f473d94d-ac3d-43d0-a838-0c9f55d622c6/'>Link</a>"} );
};
```

When I put the snippet into another editor ( e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) , the html resolves into a clickable link as it should.

What am I missing here?

(Btw. `<a href=" http://www.link.com">Link</a>` works fine, so there is a problem with the evernote:/// url type)

Comment: you can use [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/) for sharing code, instead of w3cschools.

Answer (score 1):

URL should have `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 0):

`evernote:///` is not a protocol that everybody understands. Even if you put the same link in your browser it will not work. As the previous answer suggests, you must link your href tag to a http:// or https:// protocol.

Although the w3schools page creates a link out of it, nothing happens when you actually click it.

Comment: Thank you. Actually chrome is able to understand the link the  w3schools page creates. A click triggers a "External Protocol Request" pop up, which will open the correct note in the Evernote PC/Mac Client once you accept it. This is why I dont understand that the link not resolve into a clickable link in Gmail when opening the email in Chrome.

Comment: The GMail web client is sanitizing the html body. If you navigate to the email, then "Show Original", you will see that the body of the email does contain the link, exactly as you produced it. Presumably, if the recipient was using some other way to view the message, the link could be presented to them.

Comment: Chrome opens it because you might have an extension that intercepts the evernote:// protocol. Otherwise, it is not a standard protocol for all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String body= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("<a href=\"evernote:///view/XXXXXXX/sXX/f473d94d-ac3d-43d0-a838-0c9f55d622c6/f473d94d-ac3d-43d0-a838-0c9f55d622c6/\">Link</a>");
```

Pass the string body as parameter

Comment: This answer isn't google-apps-script (or javascript), it appears to be C++ or C# - [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) is part of the .NET framework, so unless this answer is also proposing a change of development language and environment, it's not helpful, and should be downvoted, not upvoted. (Nothing personal - just trying to save viewers time and bother.)